# changing blog title to an image using filter function in child theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, parent-theme

Hey guys i'm trying to change the blog title to an image.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I tried adding this code to the css and it's working.

```
.rh-content {
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url(http:file-location.png) 10px 10px no-repeat;
/* height: 100%; */
}
```

But this is the result

[image]

The image is not showing enough. Also I want to add it to the functions.php in my child theme. i Tried this code

```
add_filter('the_title', function($title){ 
$title = '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/blah.png">' . 
$title;
return $title;
}); ?>
```

but this is the result. This is what i'm seeing when i add the filter function
[image]

This is the raw code

```
<div class="rh-content">
        <?php if (is_author() || is_archive() || is_day() || is_tag() || is_category() || is_month() || is_day() || is_year()): ?>
            <h1 style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_title); ?>">
                <?php if (is_category()): ?>
                    <?php echo single_cat_title("", true); ?>
                <?php elseif(is_tag()): ?>
                    <?php echo single_tag_title("", true); ?>
                <?php elseif(is_day()): ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_date('F dS Y'); ?>
                <?php elseif(is_month()): ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_date('Y, F'); ?>
                <?php elseif(is_year()): ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_date('Y'); ?>
                <?php elseif(is_author()): ?>
                    <?php $userdata = get_userdata($GLOBALS['author']); ?>
                    <?php echo esc_html__("Articles posted by", 'thebuilders'); ?> "<?php echo esc_attr($userdata->first_name)." ".esc_attr($userdata->last_name); ?>"
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo esc_html__("Posts", 'thebuilders'); ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </h1>
            <div style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_breadcrumbs); ?>" class="nz-breadcrumbs nz-clearfix"><?php thebuilders_ninzio_breadcrumbs(); ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if (isset($GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title']) && !empty($GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title'])): ?>
                <h1 style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_title); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title']); ?></h1>
            <?php else: ?>
                <h1 style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_title); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__("Posts", 'thebuilders'); ?></h1>
            <?php endif ?>
            <div style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_breadcrumbs); ?>" class="nz-breadcrumbs nz-clearfix"><?php thebuilders_ninzio_breadcrumbs(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

This is the url link. https://harborllc.wpengine.com/blogs/

Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your use of `the_title` filter is that the filter is applied on all uses of any title anywhere, so you're setting the title of every post and page to the image. You should use the 2nd argument passed to the filter, `$id`, to only apply your changes to the desired title:

```
function wpse_294263_title_image( $title, $id ) {
    if ( $id === 2 ) {
        $title = '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/blah.png">';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_294263_title_image' );
```

`2` should be the ID of the page the title belongs to. If it's the page set to the Posts page in *Settings > Reading* you can set this dynamically with `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )`.

The issue with your CSS implementation was that you set the image as a background but did not fit the background to the element or resize the element to suit the background. You probably want to do a mix of both:

```
.rh-content {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(http:file-location.png) left center / contain no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The `contain` value in `background` ensures that the background image is sized to fit within the background regardless of the elements size, while `height: 100px` adjusts that size so that the image then becomes a reasonable size.

Comment: i tried your code but no luck. https://pasteboard.co/H7SSo8j.png
the image is for all the webpage that's responsible for each page title. I''m going to re try the style with your suggestion. thanks

Comment: I just noticed in your screenshot that the filter method didn't even originally affect the specific title you're after, so probably isn't the title of an actual page or going through the `the_title` filter. The template code, `$GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title']` seems to be specific to your theme, so if you don't want to do it with CSS you probably need to contact the theme author.

Comment: Hmm. Your right. maybe i should need to contact them. Is there any way to just replace the code from <h1 style="">Harbor Enterprises Blog</h1> to <img src> instead? If there's no such thing then i really need to contact them. Thank you very much good sir.

Comment: If you create a child theme you might be able to replace the template entirely, and do what you wish, but if you edit it directly the change will be lost if you ever update the theme. I suggest contacting the author to find out the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the content

```
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('.rh-content h1').replaceWith(function(){
return $('<img src="https://harborllc.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Harbor-Enterprises-Logo-Transparent-White-Outline-Revised-2.png"/>', {
    html: this.innerHTML
})
})
});
```